# How do I assign Ctrl-C Ctrl-D to menu Python/Debugger in my ~/.emacs file?

Tags: key-bindings, python-mode

With a .py file open in my buffer, and the major mode being Python, there is a *menu* called Python. There is a item in it called Debugger. It has no associated keyboard shortcut.

What is the lisp command in ~/.emacs to assign Ctrl-c Ctrl-d to it?

Comment: Note that `C-c C-d` is already bound to `python-describe-at-point` so you are going to lose that binding if you rebind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing we do every night, Pinky!

```lisp
(define-key desired-keymap-here
            (kbd "your key here")
            'preferred-command-here)
```

It’s just a fill–in–the blank madlib. You already know two of the three pieces of information you need. You want to assign this to the `C-x C-d` key, so put that in as the key. You only want this binding to be active in Python mode, so the keymap is called `python-mode-map`. All you need to do now is figure out what the name of the command is.

Since Emacs is self–documenting, you can ask it! Type `C-h k` and it will prompt you for a key. When you press a key, it tells you what command is bound to that key. But here’s a secret that not many know: menus are just keys too, as far as Emacs is concerned. Instead of tying a key on your keyboard, select the menu item you are curious about. It will open up a help buffer that tells you all about that command. Insert the name in the third slot and you’re done.

Comment: No quote on the keymap argument.

Comment: Heh, you are technically correct. However, it is apparently such a common mistake that Emacs checks to see if you gave it a symbol and if you did then it evaluates it to get the keymap first. Of course, that technically makes it not a mistake any more :)

Comment: Not here. I do `(define-key 'python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") #'func)` and I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument keymapp python-mode-map)
  define-key(python-mode-map "\3\4" func)
  (progn (define-key 'python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") #'func))
  eval((progn (define-key 'python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") #'func)) t)
`. Emacs version: "GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.17.8)
 of 2023-10-06" - maybe it was added very recently?

Comment: I don’t know. I see the function `get_keymap` is called in keymap.c, and the comment says “Check that OBJECT is a keymap (after dereferencing through any symbols).  If it is, return it.”

Comment: Jim Blandy wrote the code back in 1991, and although it’s been updated since the code hasn’t actually changed much since then.

Comment: AFAICT, the comment is wrong. It is calling `indirect_function` which chases to the end of the chain of the function cell of a symbol, not its value cell.

Comment: That was my diagnosis as well, though I am confused because the very first version in 1991 did the same thing. Did it just never work? Were keymaps ever stored in the function cell? I don’t really see why they would be. Do you want to file the bug or shall I?

Comment: Please do - and thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Making it call `Findirect_variable` instead breaks things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149623/discussion-between-nickd-and-db48x).

Comment: It worked with the quote.

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
(defun python-mode-custom-hook()
  (interactive)
  (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-g") 'pdb))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'python-mode-custom-hook)`